# How to implement formatting features

Tags: c, formatting, user-input

I am trying to implement a formatting feature into my code, first of all

I read a text file which was inputted by the user, and formatting features

such as ".br", ".sp" and ".ce" are contained inside this text file.

So I am trying to make an if statement that if the program finds the word ".br" it

should immediately break and start the next word on a new line, but I really

cannot think of way to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
FILE *fp = NULL;
char file_name[257] = {'\0'};
char line[61] = {'\0'};
char word[61] = {'\0'};
int out = 0;

printf ( "Enter file name:\n");
scanf ( " %256[^\n]", file_name);

if ( ( fp = fopen ( file_name, "r")) == NULL) {
    printf ( "This file does not exist.\n");
    return 1;
}

while ( ( fscanf ( fp, "%60s", word)) == 1) {
    if ( strlen ( line) + strlen ( word) + 1 <= 60) {
        strcat ( line, " ");
        strcat ( line, word);
        out = 0;
    }
    else {
        printf ( "%s\n", line);
        strcpy ( line, word);
        out = 1;
    }

 if ((word) == ".br"){

      }
}
if ( !out) {
    printf ( "%s\n", line);
}

fclose ( fp);
return 0;
}
```

I created the IF statement for the ".br" feature but I really need help or some

clues what to actually put in the loop.

Comment: the `if` statement is outside the read loop, why? In my opinion you have to read words (%s) and check for each what is it. If it is a control (starting with a dot) you should apply the action, else just print the word. But maybe I don't understand what you asking for.

Comment: stringcompare is with `strcmp()`-family, not by `==`

Comment: yeah sorry I edited it now, I put it outside the loop by accident, but essentially it should just break the line when it sees .br and continue reading the file as normal

Comment: Yes, don't notice that. Note to the requester: don't correct your code at each comment → nobody will understand the comments. You should apply these changes in your own code to improve it and add comments or notes to indicate the results.

Comment: I am right thinking that you just bother to print to stdout the formated result? I mean if the file contains "this is my .br text to print" it should print "this is my" + BR + "text to print"?

Comment: you have a small buffer-overflow: you do not take the space (or the trailing zero) into account in your `<=60` condition

Comment: Yes, that's correct it should print " this is my" + BR + "text to print"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an if condition to compare the word to ".br". Print out the current line and set `line` to accept the next word in an empty string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char file_name[257] = {'\0'};
    char line[61] = {'\0'};
    char word[61] = {'\0'};
    int out = 0;

    printf ( "Enter file name:\n");
    scanf ( " %256[^\n]", file_name);

    if ( ( fp = fopen ( file_name, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ( "could not open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while ( ( fscanf ( fp, "%60s", word)) == 1) {
        if ( strcmp ( word, ".br") == 0) {
            printf ( "%s\n", line);
            line[0] = '\0';
            out = 1;
        }
        else if ( strlen ( line) + strlen ( word) + 1 < 60) {
            strcat ( line, " ");
            strcat ( line, word);
            out = 0;
        }
        else {
            printf ( "%s\n", line);
            strcpy ( line, word);
            out = 1;
        }
    }
    if ( !out) {
        printf ( "%s\n", line);
    }

    fclose ( fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help, I fully understand it now

Answer (score 0):

```
if( 0 == strcmp( word, ".br" ) )
{
    printf( "%s", line );
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

Note strings cannot be compared with `==`, must use something like `strcmp()`

the posted code needs a bit of rearranging so characters are not placed into `line[]` until after checking if the token `word[]` is NOT a format sequence.